# Bridge/Join Table for a Many to Many Relationship between One Table and Multiple Others

Tags: database, database-design, sql, sql-server, relational-database

**Background**

I have a relational database an I want to have a table that contains flags. I want multiple tables in my database to have a many to many relationship with the flag table.

**Options**

I could go about this two ways (I think):

1. I could create a join table between the flag table and each table I want it to have a many to many relationship with.

```
|Table1ID|FlagID|    |Table2ID|FlagID|    |Table3ID|FlagID|
|--------+------|    |--------+------|    |--------+------|
|   1    |  4   |    |   4    |  2   |    |   8    |  3   |
|  ...   | ...  |    |  ...   | ...  |    |  ...   | ...  |
```

2. I could create a join table that listed the table, the row id and the id for the flag.

```
|TableName|ID|FlagID|
|---------+--+------|
| Table1  |1 |  4   |
| Table2  |4 |  2   |
| Table3  |8 |  3   |
|  ...    |..| ...  |
```

**Question**

Obviously, I would like to go with option two. Is there any reason I shouldn't do this?

Comment: Why is option 2 the obvious choice?

Comment: I think option 1 is actually the more sensible choice. I just want to know if I could reduce the number of lookup tables since they all have one in common. Ie, I'm lazy.

Comment: I would probably go with option two myself.  However, it should be noted that option two involves storing database metadata, namely table names, in a user table.  There are downsides to this but they will probably never become real problems for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, when I needed this capability, I employed a Generic Key strategy.  It looks like this:

Generic Key Type Table

```
GenericKeyTypeID   TableName    FieldName
       1            Table1      FlagID
       2            Table2      FlagID
       3            Table3      FlagID
```

You can have as many combinations of table and field in your Generic Key Type table as you want.

Then, in your linking table, you create two fields: `GenericKeyID` and `GenericKeyTypeID`.  In the `GenericKeyTypeID` field, you put the ID corresponding to one of the combinations above.  In the `GenericKeyID`, you put the ID of the corresponding target table record.

So for example, your Table1 example would look like this:

```
GenericKeyTypeID   GenericKeyID
      1                4
```

This will work for any field combination.  It is not specific to your Flag field.

Comment: Thanks! I like this idea better because it means I can have flags that only pertain to some columns and not others (although I'm not sure that will happen.)

Comment: Do you ever have problems with storing database metadata like @WalterMitty mentioned? That was actually the thing the concerned me the most about my "option 2" and why I said that just using join tables was more sensible.

Comment: Not really.  It's just names.